# dd and dump freeze the console output

Tags: laravel, laravel-10, iterm2

I'm not sure what happened, but I was in the middle of debugging some console commands and suddenly neither `dd()` or `dump()` work in the console. All output freezes and I have to force quit `ctrl + c` to stop the task.

These aren't large pieces of data I am dumping. Even if I do `dd('test')` it locks up.

However, I can do `var_dump($var); exit;` without issue.

I've tried restarting iTerm2 (v3.4.23) but that didn't help.

This didn't happen after a crash, system restart, or installing new software. I was just in the middle of an active session in the console and suddenly this behavior started on all console scripts I use `dd()` or `dump()` in.

I'm running my local test env using Laravel Herd.

What could be happening here?

Comment: This was a problem with Laravel Herd. Forcing the service to quit, restarting it, then restarting all services it manages resolved the issue.

Comment: Well, old terminals would freeze when typing a DC3 character (CTRL-s), which is 0x13.